# C++ How To Correctly Have Abstract Return Type?

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract

I need the below method to return an abstract-Type `ALMObjectC`, however I found this can only be done via Pointer; but when I declare this, the compiler states:

```
Error: no suitable conversion function from "ALMObjectC" to "ALMObjectC*" exists.
```

So how can I resolve this issue? 
Below is the method in question:

```
ALMObjectC* AlmRESTC::findChild(int ref){
    //objectSet(ref) => ALMObjectC 
    for(list<ALMObjectC>::iterator cons = objectSet.begin(); (cons != objectSet.end()); cons++){
        if (distance(objectSet.begin(), cons) == ref)
            return *cons;
    }
}
```

Comment: Error message is pretty clear..

Comment: Consider to return  a reference: `ALMObjectC& AlmRESTC::findChild(int ref)`

Comment: @manni66 using a reference will not allow him to use polymorphism

Comment: @Xatyrian it will.

Comment: Ah yeah, you're right ahah

Comment: @manni66 it won't only static can work like that.

Comment: @Olivier10178 no, that has nothing to do with static.

Comment: @Olivier10178 please can I ask you to [be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) and refrain from calling others. Thank you.

Comment: @Olivier10178 An there is stated that you **have to use** static?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*cons` will give you the object you stored, which has the type `ALMObjectC`. if you want to return the address of this object, you must do

```
return &(*cons)
```

Comment: I.e. return the value of this pointer, to be the co-domain of another pointer. Noice.